# How should I design this? Nhibernate unit of work in a method

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, unit-of-work

I am using asp.net mvc and nhibernate with the unit of work pattern.

I have something like this

```
public bool IsSomething()
{
   unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
   var myGetStuff = repo.GetStuff(1);

   if(myGetStuff == null)
   {
       return false;
   }  

   var somethingElse = myGetStuff.GetSomethingElse();

   if(somethngElse == null)
   {
      return false;
   } 

   return true;
}
```

So in my if statements if something is null and I need it not to be null I just get out of the statement.

This is opposed as having nested if statements that could be like nested 4 or 5 times to do null checks.

```
public bool IsSomething()
{
   unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
   var myGetStuff = repo.GetStuff(1);

   if(myGetStuff != null)
   {
      var somethingElse = myGetStuff.GetSomethingElse();

       if(somethngElse != null)
       {
          // some more check heere ( could have another few if statements null checks here)
       } 
   }  
}
```

So I find the first way much easier to read then nested levels of if statements.

My problem is that even if you do a query in nhibernate you **must** wrap it around in a transaction and at the end do either a rollback or commit.

Option 1

```
  public bool IsSomething()
    {
       unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
       var myGetStuff = repo.GetStuff(1);

       if(myGetStuff == null)
       {
           unitOfWork.Commit();
           return false;
       }  

       var somethingElse = myGetStuff.GetSomethingElse();

       if(somethngElse == null)
       {
        unitOfWork.Commit();
          return false;
       } 

       unitOfWork.Commit();
       return true;
    }
```

This way I don't like as you have to keep putting commit everywhere. If possible I would love to have just one commit(unless I have more than one unit of work transaction)

So then I though why not put it in a finally like this

```
  public bool IsSomething()
    {
     try
     {
           unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
           var myGetStuff = repo.GetStuff(1);

           if(myGetStuff == null)
           {
               return false;
           }  

           var somethingElse = myGetStuff.GetSomethingElse();

           if(somethngElse == null)
           {

              return false;
           } 

           return true;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       { 
          unitOfWork.RollBack();
       }
       finally
       {
          unitOfWork.Commit();
       }
    }
```

I like this but then I realized what happens if the commit fails? It won't rollback and the exception won't be caught.

So anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: do you only read or do you update/insert also?

Comment: Depends on the method some might have a mix of read/update/insert or some may just have  a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code of your looks rather problematic to me, especially when there are nested unit of work calls (how do you handle those?). What I would do is to open the unit of work (and the transactions) in the calling code (the Controller in your case as you use ASP.Net MVC) and not the IsSomething function. It would look something like this:

```
try
{
    unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
    // some code
    var isSomething = IsSomeThing()
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
   unitOfWork.RollBack();
}
finally
{
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

The IsSomething function would then look simply like this

```
public bool IsSomething()
{
   var myGetStuff = repo.GetStuff(1);

   if(myGetStuff == null)
   {
      return false;
   }  

   var somethingElse = myGetStuff.GetSomethingElse();

   if(somethngElse == null)
   {

       return false;
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what a nested unit of work is. This is something I did think about but not sure about it. IsSomething is in my Service layer where all my business logic lies. I setup my service layer so that it is in it's own project and tried to make in as independent from mvc as possible so that I can take that project and use it in a different project ( say a webservice). So it would be nice if it is with the service layer not that I make it a .dll and then all of a sudden you got to have to wrap it in UoW. Then I was unsure should a UoW be in a controller in the first place?

Comment: Also what happens in your scenario if you need multiple transactions?

Comment: What I meant by a nested unit of work is the following: You have a piece of code (let's say a controller). At the start you make your UoW.BeginTransaction() call and at the end UoW.Commit. And then inside this controller you call your IsSomething function which has also a UoW.Commit. Wouldn't this interfere with your first UoW.BeginTransaction? What I do is I alway start, commit and rollback my transactions in the http module.

Comment: As for the multiple transactions, I don't have any. I always model my controller to have a single transaction scope.

Comment: Well since my thinking is that in the controller should not know anything about database stuff I should not run into the nested problem. I could in my service layer have a method that the controller calls and that calls some private method. That could be an option. Like I said not sold on it being in the controller yet.

Comment: Your approach is certainly something what the textbook would say, but I don't see the benefit to add an extra service layer with all the added complexity just to avoid the controller-database dependency. I for myself use the service layer only if I have calls to multiple repositories (for coordination purposes).... And mostly I ditch the repository, too.

Comment: .... And isn't the NHibernate session already the unit of work? Why abstract this. Will you ever change the ORM you use in an existing application. I don't think so. IMHO, you'll likely have to write the application from scratch.

Comment: ... And if you do have to abstract the controller away from the database, you can still use my approach. Just move the controller code I wrote to the service layer (and don't use the begin,commit,rollback in the IsSomething function ... it's really just a helper function that will never be used by its own)